# Why isn't my react client not receiving emitted messages?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

im building a chat app using express and react and socket.io, and everything works, except that when I emit message from my server, it doesn't catch it in the client. Why is that? My code is:

index.js (server)

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('join-room', data => {
    console.log(`Joining room ${data.room}`);
    socket.join(data.room);
  });

  socket.on('leave-room', data => {
    console.log(`Leaving room room ${data.room}`);
    socket.leave(data.room);
  });

  socket.on('new-message', data => {
    console.log(`Sending message to room ${data.room}`);
    socket.to(data.room).emit('new-message', data.message);
  });
});
```

JoinRoom.js (react)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('new-message', data => {
      console.log('getting new message');
      setMessages([...messages, data]);
    });
  }, [messages]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit('join-room', { room: id });

    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await req.get('/api/room/' + id);
      setRoom(response.data);

      const _messages = await req.get('/api/messages/' + id);
      setMessages(_messages.data.docs);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [id]);

  const send = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('new-message', {
      room: id,
      message: newMessage
    });
    const data = {
      message: newMessage,
      user: 'Mikolaj',
      roomId: id
    };
    req.post('/api/messages/send', data);
    setNewMessage('');
  };
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if I say ```socket.emit(...)``` in index.js, it works, but i want to send it to a specific room

Comment: Did you solve this?